# SQL: default behavior when using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have the following query:

```
SELECT colA, colB, colC, colD  
FROM table  
GROUP BY colC, colD
```

This query doesn't run on `MS SQL Server`, because columns `colA` and `colB` are not part of the group by and are not in an aggregate.

Now, I **know** that all the other columns will have the same values inside each group. So I could fix this by choosing an aggregate like `MAX` for `colA` and `colB`, or just add them to the `GROUP BY`.

However, here's my problem: the above query is just an example, but what I really have are several very long queries with lots of columns. What I want to know is: can I set a default aggregate function for the remaining columns or something similar, so I **don't** have to include all the remaining columns manually in the `GROUP BY` or apply an aggregate manually to all the select pieces?

Comment: The answer is NO! The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Here is a good consideration for you: If you have already specified ColA, ColB, ... ColN in your SELECT list, it will be very quick to Copy-Paste them into the GROUP BY clause :) Looks like you don't need a complicated solution for this.

Comment: Let's say you have a car with no tires, you want to add all tires. Can you add just one and expect the car to do the rest of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO.

Instead, you can get only one row **for every couple colC-colD**,  with few control of what values you get from other columns. You can use a row numbering function.

Add a column that numbers rows by group (for every couple **colC-colD**):

```
select colA, colB, colC, colD, 
row_number() over (partition by colC, colD order by colA, colB) as Sequence
FROM table
```

In MSSQL you can not use a row_number in where clause. If you want to see only a row for every couple **colC-colD**, you must put all in a subquery:

```
select colA, colB, colC, colD
from (
  select colA, colB, colC, colD, 
  row_number() over (partition by colC, colD order by colA, colB) as Sequence
  FROM table  
) T
where Sequence = 1
```

With this method you see only one row of all the other columns but *you cannot choose an aggregate function*.

All you can choose is the order criteria, which means which row will have the number "1", changing the part `order by colA, colB`.